# Need to find top space consuming files/dirs in python

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm very new to python and still learning new stuff... trying to print 2 things here : all files/dirs recursively in a filesystem and all files taking space more than 10 G and print them in 2 diff lists... i know there is something seriously wrong with the code... but can someone please help and point out where am i going wrong.

```
import os
import sys

diskName=sys.argv[1]

class diskUsage():

    def __init__(self,diskName):
        self.name=diskName

    def print_dir_content(self):
        for child in (os.listdir(diskName)):
            childPath=os.path.join(diskName,child)
            if os.path.isdir(childPath):
                print_dir_content(childPath)
            else:
                print(childPath)

    def check_space_usage(self):
        filesizes=[]
        for file in print_dir_content.childPath:
            size=os.path.getsize(file)
            if size > 10:
                filesizes.append(size)
                print (filesizes)
            else: pass


x=diskUsage(diskName)
x.print_dir_content()
x.check_space_usage()
```

Comment: The indentation is seriously wrong. Methods print_dir_content and check_space_usage are incorrectly indented.

Comment: is it just the indentation ? i cant run it even after correcting that ?

Comment: Indentation in Python is a part of language grammar.

Comment: Unless you need/want to write your own recursive procedure, you may want to refactor with [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to visit all the files in question.

Comment: forgot to mention... wanted a nested structure.. did not want to use os.walk()

Comment: Are you getting errors/exceptions?  If you haven't spent any time in The Tutorial, you may want to look through the [9. Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) section : you have defined instance attributes and you are not accessing them correctly.

Comment: no im not getting any errors exceptions as yet... this is a very rough sketch... was first trying to see if this works... and gives me something

Comment: `print_dir_content` doesn't return or yield anything yet you are using it as the for loop iterator in `check_space_usage`.  Maybe look at [4.6 Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

Comment: @wwii - thanks , will go through this link...